# How can i protect an NvIndex from being recreated, without the need of another NvIndex

Tags: tpm

TL;DR: (How) is it possible to ensure that the name of an NvIndex changes every time it is created without the need of any other object?

I want to create a key inside the TPM (v2) that should be protected by an TPM_NT_PIN_FAIL NvIndex.
I know how do to that, but i think that an attacker might be able to delete the NvIndex and recreate it with the pinCount set to zero or with a very high pinLimit.

As far as i know recreating an NvIndex does not change his name, so a policy relying on the NvIndex would still be satisfied.
I had an idea how to make sure that the name of the NvIndex changes every time it is created but this requires a second NvIndex.

This is my current idea:

1. Create an NvIndex as TPM_NT_COUNTER
2. Increment the counter
3. Read the counters value
4. Create a Policy to allow read access to the NvIndex but allow only one write:

   Policy Session A: ***Policy_CC*** NV_READ

   Policy Session B: ***Policy_Nv***  the value of the counter index must be equal to its current value, ***Policy_NvWritten*** the TPM_NT_PIN_FAIL NvIndex must not have the TPMA_NV_WRITTEN flag set, ***Policy_CC*** NV_WRITE

   Policy to restrict access to the NvIndex: ***Policy_Or*** Policy Session A, Policy Session B
5. Create the NvIndex with a password and the policy
6. Write pinCount and pinLimit to the NvIndex
7. Increment the counter

It may occur that many of such keys need to be created, so the need of two NvIndexes for each key could become a problem.

Comment: If you are concerned about an attacker deleting the index, why not just protect against deletion (with a policy, or for example TPMA_NV_POLICY_DELETE) instead of this complication?

Comment: I am not concerned about an attacker deleting the index , i am concerned about an attacker recreating it and bypassing the antihammering system. I need to delete the index once the key protected by it gets deleted. Besides i believe that TPMA_NV_POLICY_DELETE requires the use of the platform hierachie.

Comment: You cannot recreate an index without deleting it. So protect the index against deletion. If you need to delete it yourself, then protect it with an auth that only you know.

Comment: You are right, but for me this would lead to another problem. When the software is deinstalled it must free all of the ressources it has allocated inside the tpm, at this point user input may not be possible. I would have to use some sort of hard coded key as auth value and this is something i do not want to use.

Comment: OK... Is your application defining the index? If so, you must have got access to at least the owner auth, right? Can you use the same mechanism to obtain the auth when uninstalling?